# "The earliest being" or "the earliest of which is"?

Tags: british-english

I have just received the following correction:

> These date back to trigonometric and logarithmic tables, the earliest of which <s>being</s> [**is**]  a base-10 logarithm table from Briggs (1617).

with the suggestion:

> either use "the earliest being ..." or "the earliest of which is ...".

Please could someone expand on which is better for what context, or are they interchangeable? Only British English please.

Comment: There is a [rule](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z4HI0RQIDK0C&lpg=PA710&dq=%22of%20which%20being%22&pg=PA710#v=onepage&q=%22of%20which%20being%22&f=false) here. Don't use -ing verbs after *which* when using this construction to form a subordinating clause. You can use -ing verbs after demonstratives such as *this* or *these*.

Comment: So a third alternative is " ... the earliest of these being a base-10 ..."